# Why does it not use "is heard asking" but "heard asking"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

> He is then heard asking: "Is it just me?"

I can't  understand that sentence meaning.
Does that mean that he heard about asking or he heard and asking?
And is it possible "He heard asking"?
I think "is heard" is uncorrected in grammar...  please teach me!

Answer (score 1):

*He heard asking* is syntactically correct, but changing the sentence to use it makes the sentence mean something completely different.

In the below, I will remove the *then* from the original version since it's not directly related to the difference in meaning.

> 1. He *is* heard asking: "Is it just me?"
>      → Somebody overhears him ask, "Is it just me?"

In this version, somebody overhears him asking a question.

> 2. He heard asking: "Is it just me?"
>      → He overhears the question "Is it just me?"

But without the *is*, *he* is now the one doing the hearing, not somebody else. Further, *asking* is now being used as a noun rather than a verb—and what he's hearing is *(an) asking*—a question. *Asking* becomes a thing rather than an action.

---

Note that while *he heard asking* is valid syntax, it's also an unusual way of phrasing the meaning described in 2. above. It would more typically be written as *he heard a question*.

Comment: #2 is awkwardly worded, though. Most would say, _He heard someone ask: "Is it just me?"_

Answer (score 1):

> George is then heard asking: "Is it just me?"

"George is heard" is passive: it means "somebody hears/can hear George".

"Asking" does not change this: it is still not George doing the hearing.